# Sharing emoticons on Android through FacebookAPI

Tags: android, facebook, api, share, emoji

I need to share text with emoticons, something like this [image]

For now I have this variant:

[image]

Is there way to do it?

I've tried to search code for this emoji but didn't find it - all of the emoticon's codes are only for old versions.

What if I will share image for this emoji? Will it work like smile?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do it, at least now.
I can set emoticons for title through codes but for description I can not.